# Explanations over "Doing It For You" in answers

Tags: discussion, answers

A rather irritating trend that I have spotted in StackOverflow is the majority of those that ask questions accept answers that simply fix their code instead of explaining why it was broken in the first place. I understand that it is just people people want to get their code fixed as quickly as possible but it seems to be

So my question is, is it better to just fix the code rather than explaining what is wrong? It seems to go against what the site is for but it also seems to be what the people want.

Comment: In my experience I find that including a proper explanation in my answers nets me the 'accepted' mark more often than not, actually.

Comment: Only copy/paste coders would accept a code answer without an explanation of how the code works.  I'm not sure there's much you can do about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it better to just fix the code rather than explaining what is wrong?

In an ideal world, explaining what's wrong would always the "better" thing. However, as you note, it is often not worth it because the OP isn't interested in actually developing as a programmer - they just want this piece of code to *work*.

Signs that hint at such questions:

- Does the tone of the question, and the way it is put, suggest that the OP isn't interested in learning?
- Is the question a localized syntax problem ("this code doesn't work") that isn't going to help anybody but the OP, ever? Then it's not really a good fit for Stack Overflow. Vote to close.
- Is the question one of those that have a trillion duplicates on the site already? Consider ignoring it.*

In these cases, it may be pointless to invest too much effort - even if you take account Stack Overflow's mission of being a long-term archive: the great answer will often be lost in the noise. Those questions where the OP might actually be interested in an extended explanation, are usually easy to spot.

<sub>* You could theoretically go and look for a duplicate that already answers the question, but there often is no point - the question will be answered with quick fixes, one of those answers will be accepted, and your duplicate-finding work will be for nought.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, one of the goals of StackExchange is to make the Internet a better place. Explaining why a piece of code in a question on SO is broken rather than just fixing it meets the goal, way more than the quick code fix does.

We should always keep in mind that the reputation points we earn by answering questions isn't the only positive thing that comes out of our answers. One might earn a quick 25 rep by providing the correct piece of code, without any form of explanation. But if your answer is more detailed, in the end it will end up helping more people, which in turn will earn you the well-deserved reputation points. Programmers will eventually stumble upon your answers, and will upvote it because it's a great answer and because it really helped them, as opposed to this quick code fix qhich gives no useful information.

Comment: "one of the goals of StackExchange is to make the Internet a better place."  Can you tell me where you read that?

Comment: @JohnnyBones [Here](http://stackexchange.com/): "_From our core of Q&A, to community blogs and real-time chat, we provide experts with the tools they need to make The Internet a better place._"

Answer (score 2):

```
"So my question is, is it better to just fix 
the code rather than explaining what is wrong?"
```

Personally, I say it's *always better to explain the fix*.  As often as possible, I try to provide some explanation as to what changes I made, and why those changes are made.   I also try to provide a fiddle when appropriate, as well as MDN links when appropriate.

In my experience, when I've answered a question and others have provided the same / similar answer, my answer gets accepted if it is "better documented" and thought out.

Answer (score 1):

"So my question is, is it better to just fix the code rather than explaining what is wrong?"

Sometimes you have to.  However, often times I forgo points by not giving the perfect, complete answer but rather taking the OP to the edge and leaving him/her a little room to cross the finish line on their own.  Sometimes people jump in, take my code, finish it and get the glory.  Oh well.  I continue to do what I do because I think crossing that line on your own is the greatest part about being a programmer.  When I can, I sometimes give tidbits on why a particular answer will or won't work.  Having it all spelled out feels like cheating, and I don't want to cheat myself or cheat others.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is it better to just fix the code rather than explaining what is wrong?

It depends, like so many things on this site.  It's important to keep some perspective here.  What you need to be asking yourself is, "Is the answer helpful?".  Some answers can be helpful despite having no, or very little, explanation of code they provide.  Perhaps the code provided is written/formatted in such a way ask to make the solution obvious, and the question is written in such a way that it's clear that it could be understood.  (A more advanced question can often assume a certain level of knowledge from the reader, more basic questions can't.)  If you honestly feel that someone knowledgeable enough to ask that question would most certainly understand the answer, without needing a detailed explanation, then you may feel that the answer is helpful.  If you feel that the "target audience" of the question is unlikely to understand the solution given just the code, or with a shorter explanation, then you may feel that the answer is not helpful.

Once you've determine if the answer is helpful or not, you now know how you should vote.  If you feel that a particular aspect of the answer is unclear, or may not be understood by readers, or just that it really needs to be explained, you can potentially add some explanation yourself in comments.  I don't do this a *lot*, but sometimes adding a bit of useful but not crucial info in comments, to be seen by those looking for more information about the answer, can go there.  If the answer's author really likes the comments, they may incorporate them into the post.